# Get ID from m2m instance

Tags: django, django-models

In a model with a M2M relationship. Is there any way to get the id of the field of this relation in a signal?

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    field1 = ...
    bar = models.ManyToManyField(Bar)

@receiver(post_save/m2m_changed, sender=Foo)
def whatever(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # get the ID of bar instance here
```

I want to be able to get the id of the Bar instance being used. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE]:

```
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed

def whatever(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print(kwargs['pk_set'])

m2m_changed.connect(whatever, sender=Foo.bar.through)
```

[OLD]:

`instance.bar.values('id')` or `instance.bar.values_list('id', flat=True)`

Comment: This way I'll get the list with all the relations, not the one is being saved.

Answer (score 0):

Use `m2m_changed`

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Foo)
def whatever(sender, instance, action, pk_set, **kwargs):
    if action == "pre_add":
         print pk_set
```

**pk_set**

> For the pre_add, post_add, pre_remove and post_remove actions, this is a set of primary key values that have been added to or removed from the relation. For the pre_clear and post_clear actions, this is None.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#m2m-changed